# How to move a feral cat

Tags: cats

I have been feeding a feral cat since she was born under my neighbor's house 5 years ago. When she was younger, I hired someone to trap and have her spayed. Even after all this time, she will let me pet her when she comes to my door for food but if I pass her on the street, she runs from me. In the past, I have tried to bring her inside but she went absolutely crazy trying to get out. I am planning a move in several months and I can't leave her behind. I love her too much. I have moved twice in the last 5 years but stayed in my own neighborhood just for her. Each time, I moved just blocks from where I lived and coaxed her to the new location with food. This time I will be moving to the northern part of the state to be closed to my mother. Do you have any suggestions?